# How to add material-symbols to the Next.js project?

Tags: next.js, google-material-icons

I use Next.js v13.2. I want to add [material-symbols](https://fonts.google.com/icons) to my project.

I want to use it like

```
<span className="material-symbols-rounded">face</span>
```

I found that Next.JS replaced `head.js` file with [Metadata](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata) but I can't find how to add CDNs. Previously I used it like this (but it didn't work correctly. On refresh it rendered icon name instead of icon itself)

```
// app/head.tsx
export default function Head(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Project Name</title>
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200&display=optional"
        precedence="default"
        rel="stylesheet"
        precedence
      />
  )
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `npm` package: [`material-symbols`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-symbols)

This does all the legwork in importing Material Symbols as a font and setting up the CSS, and gives us flexibility in how we import it.

[The README has much more detailed usage info](https://github.com/marella/material-symbols/tree/main/material-symbols#readme), but I think in your case (using Next.js), you'd want to either:

- Import it globally in JS in the `_app.tsx` file:

  ```ts
  import "material-symbols";
  ```
- Import it in SCSS in a global style file (e.g. `styles/globals.scss`):

  ```scss
  @import "material-symbols";
  ```
- **Preferred**: Import is as-needed in the modular SCSS files for each component:

  ```scss
  // ExampleComponent.module.scss
  @import "material-symbols";

  ...
  ```

  ```tsx
  // ExampleComponent.tsx
  import style from "./Example.module.scss";

  ...

  <span className={style["material-symbols-rounded"]}>face</span>
  ```

I prefer the last approach because it sets you up for when you need to modify the default styling. For example:

```scss
// ExampleComponent.module.scss
...

// Modify imported material-symbols style
.material-symbols-rounded {
  font-size: theme.$medium-symbol;
}
```